# Align icons and text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the text to be placed to the right of each icon but it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I've tried setting the .panel display to table but it looks like a mess.

```css
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  /*#F7F7F7;*/
  display: none; //With a function it's then displayed as Block
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
}

.lock {
  float: right;
}

.status {
  float: left;
}

.status_icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: table-cell;
}

.lock_icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="status">
    <img src="Iconos/closed.png" alt="Closed" class="status_icon" onclick="stat(event,this);">
    <p class="stat_text">Current status: Closed</p>
  </div>
  <div class="lock">
    <img src="Iconos/locked.png" alt="Locked" class="lock_icon" onclick="lock(event,this);">
    <p class="lock_text">Current lock: Locked</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can be solved easily with flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Remove table from .panel and keep to .status, .lock

Comment: @AAShakil but .panel is never displayed as table, it is displayed as block.

Comment: making `.status` > `display:flex` will be the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display:flex` would be best approach to achieve this result. Try this CSS code.

```
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.lock {
  display: flex;
}

.status {
  display: flex;
}

.status_icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lock_icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why do you still use float: right and float: left on the classes with display: flex?

Comment: happy to help, however i have made a little change to my answer for better result. try that out...thank you for suggestion @MrBuggy